# MPMoviePlayerController gives an error while playing stream in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, url, video

I want to play a live stream video from an url in MPMoviePlayerController. I got the link with playing the video on UIWebView. UIWebView gives an output when it launches a MPMoviePlayerController, as NSLog. And it plays the stream without any problems!

```
setting movie path:
http://ibbtks.noc.com.tr/ibbesm/bagdat2lq.stream/playlist.m3u8?k=ffd81df8cfee8f9259eff91dc9a483c4
```

I got that video url from NSLog, and put it into a MPMoviePlayerController. That's code that I used,

```
- (void)playMovie
{    
    NSURL* myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ibbtks.noc.com.tr/ibbesm/kadikoylq.stream/playlist.m3u8"];

    NSURL* appleUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8"];

    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL:myUrl];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    _moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

It plays the appleUrl stream with no problem, but when I try to play myUrl, it's always loading and it gives an error. The error output is,

```
Did finish with error: Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x99a9760 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

When I try to play this link on UIWebView or safari, it plays the video successfully, and as I said, it gives me the url as NSLog that I used. But when I try to play this url myself, I got an error. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try catch the error??

Comment: What do you mean try catch the error? I already cathced the error with the delegate method and wrote the output. It wasn't showing something before that.

Comment: Check this discusiion.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191821/cannot-get-the-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-to-play-my-media-file

Comment: Any solution on this?