# ios video streaming error

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app i need to stream videos from a share point site. I am using MPMoviePlayer controller for video streaming. But i am getting a black screen with the following error :

playback failed with error description:

> Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0xbba7b90 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

What does this error mean? Can i know if this is an authentication issue. Or the problem with the share point site.

```
NSURL *streamURL=[NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
 credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                                       initWithUser: UserName
                                       password: Password
                                       persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
        protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                                 initWithHost:host
                                                 port:port
                                                 protocol: @"https"
                                                 realm:realm
                                              authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];
        [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage]
         setDefaultCredential: credential
         forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace];

        NSLog(@"streamURL = %@",streamURL);
        _streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleMPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [_streamPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.documentView.frame.size.width, self.documentView.frame.size.height)];
        _streamPlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
        _streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        _streamPlayer.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        [_streamPlayer setContentURL:streamURL];
        [_streamPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_streamPlayer play];
```

Comment: Unfortunately the video you are trying to play is not iOS compatible. Try with another URL :)

Comment: But i have'nt posted the video url. I uploaded a .mov , .mp4 and .m3u8 to the sharepoint site and tried to stream from mpmovieplayercontroller. But get the same response

Comment: use ... fileURLWithPath:, not URLWithString: .. may help in your case:

Comment: fileURLWithPath is for a local file, right. mine is a remote server url, so URLWithString may be right

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191821/cannot-get-the-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-to-play-my-media-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194776/how-to-play-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller